# How to specify more than one user in HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to add ad more that one user to a response redirect in my web app. But am not sure on how to go about it.

Here is the code that checks if `user1` logs in and then redirects to a certain page:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name == "User1")
                {
                    Response.Redirect("~/Clients/Users/User.aspx");

                }
```

So if `user2` logs in I want that user to go to the user.aspx page as well.

Do I need to duplicate the above code and change `user1` to `user2` or is there a simpler way of achieving this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name == "User1" || 
    HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name == "User2") 
{
}
```

Double-pipe means 'or'.